# Subqueries in hive with where clause

Tags: hive

Can we join two tables with where clause in hive?
In SQL I tried and its working, but in hive it's not working as hive doesn't support subqueries in where clause

```
select t.name,t2.addr from trail t
join trail2 t2
on t.name=t2.name
where marks > (select marks from trail where name='sa) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Query will not work.

Hive 0.13 supports only IN/NOT IN or EXISTS/NOT EXISTS in [where clause](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause)